# how to get the usernames of instagram accounts that a specific public account is following?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I need to know the people that a specific public instagram account is following. suppose I know the public account's username is 'PUBLIC_ACCOUNT'. how can I get the usernames of accounts that 'PUBLIC_ACCOUNT' is following. Should I use instagram api or something like that? Should I use web scraping? Do I need to have special permissions for that? I'm wondering if there is a simple python web scraping solution without any special permissions.

Comment: Yes, you should use the API. You should not attempt to scrape Instagram.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Are you sure Instagram lets me do so through their API? @DanielRoseman